# Can someone explain the meaning of this line of code?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
```

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: probably `pcl'` is an name space for your library that you included.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Answer (score 1):

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
```

`cloud` is a variable - the name `Ptr` implies it's a (possibly "smart") pointer, to a `PointCloud<PointXYZ>` which sounds like some kind of container of 3D points, initialised with a raw pointer (from `new`) to a default-constructed `PointCloud<PointXYZ>`.  That *probably* means there won't be any points in the "cloud" yet.

The `pcl::` prefixes imply your "point cloud library" is in a `namespace` called `pcl` (if you look in the library's header file, likely most of the file will be surrounded by `namespace pcl { ... }`).

Afterwards, you could use "`cloud->` *function_name* `(` *args...* `)`" to perform an operation on the cloud - check the cloud type or docs for available functions, data members etc..

Answer (score 0):

In summary you need more experience with C++ to use this library but:

1- probably `pcl'` is an name space for your library that you included.

2- `<pcl::PointXYZ>` is the template type.

3- `cloud` is a sample of your object!

4- `new` allocate memory for `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` and send the pointer to the `cloud` constructor argumen!